# Путь до AppData\Local в профиле пользователя

Tags: windows, powershell

Привет, пишу скрипт удаления кэша из определенной папки, вроде-бы ничего сложного.. Но проблема в том что имя пользователя на разных пк разное а кэш находится по адресу [C:\Users..имя пользователя..\AppData\Local]. Как сделать так чтобы при выводе [Get-ChildItem -Force C:\Users] извлечь из вывода имя пользователя(наверное присвоив его переменной) и перейти в его AppData?

Answer (score 1):

Текущего залогинившегося пользователя можно узнать через класс win32_computersystem.Метод Replace адаптировать под свой случай.Вместо DESKTOP-VDPOOCS\ подставить свою подстроку.Подставить переменную $username в путь.

```
$getusername=Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserName
$username=$getusername.Replace("DESKTOP-VDPOOCS\","")
$username
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужный вам путь можно найти в переменной окружения LOCALAPPDATA (`$env:LOCALAPPDATA`)

Еще один допустимый вариант - через переменную окружения USERPROFILE, `"$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Local"`.

Непосредственно имя текущего пользователя можно найти в переменной окружения USERNAME (`$env:USERNAME`) - но при определении пути до профиля пользователя на нее завязываться нельзя: в некоторых случаях профиль может называться по-другому.

Также в powershell пути до специальных папок можно запрашивать через метод [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[Environment]::GetFolderPath('LocalApplicationData')
```

Полный список возможных параметров метода GetFolderPath можно найти на msdn в описании [перечисления Environment.SpecialFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Использую такой способ:

```
(Get-childitem "\\$comp\c`$\Users\" -Exclude 'Administrator','admin','root','Public').fullname
```